# R shift() and diff()

Tags: r, data.table

Why does the expression shift(.SD) works fine, while diff(.SD) results in the following error:  non-numeric argument to binary operator?

An example to illustrate my point: I need to compute first difference for two variables ('value' and 'value2')

```
require(data.table)
df <-data.table(group=rep(c(1,2),each=3),value=c(10,20,25,5,10,15),value2=c(100,200,250,50,100,150))
setkey(df,group)
n1<-c('value','value2')
n2<-paste('d', n1, sep='.')

df[,(n2):=.SD-shift(.SD), by=group,.SDcols=n1] # works fine!
df[,(n2):=diff(.SD), by=group,.SDcols=n1] # produces the error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to apply `diff` on `vector` and also the output of `diff` is one element less than the original length of vector.  So, concatenate with `NA` or other element of interest is needed to make the `length` right

```
df[, (n2) := lapply(.SD, function(x) c(NA, diff(x))), by=group,.SDcols=n1]
df
#   group value value2 d.value d.value2
#1:     1    10    100      NA       NA 
#2:     1    20    200      10      100
#3:     1    25    250       5       50
#4:     2     5     50      NA       NA
#5:     2    10    100       5       50
#6:     2    15    150       5       50
```

NOTE: In addition, `shift` can also applied through the same method as above

```
df[, (n2) := lapply(.SD, shift), by=group,.SDcols=n1] 
df
#   group value value2 d.value d.value2
#1:     1    10    100      NA       NA
#2:     1    20    200      10      100
#3:     1    25    250      20      200
#4:     2     5     50      NA       NA
#5:     2    10    100       5       50
#6:     2    15    150      10      100
```

Comment: I don't see why it'd be better to apply shift on vector compared to .SD